# Problem with compiling app in Delphi 10.4

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey

I am compiling a simple app in Delphi 10.4 for iOS, and the following error occurs:

> [PAClient Error] Error: E6665 Cannot open file "/Users/techtrs/PAServer/scratch-dir/techtrs/ImpactoSFA.launchscreen/partial_info.plist". No such file or directory

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: [This](https://en.delphipraxis.net/topic/3844-big-problem-with-infoplist-ios) suggests you may have an issue with your deployment

Comment: What kind? I just created a new project with one form and config the bundle identifier acconding to mac and bind delphi and mac and try to compile.

Comment: @Dr.T: Did you follow the link that Dave provided?

Comment: No, I realize this link now. I Will check and let you know.

Comment: I read the solution but it is not my case. I Will try to install everything again.